# Only checked li should move at a time with sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I've a list of items and with this I've give checkbox. I've use sortable function of jQuery for drag & drop that item. When I check item only that item should be move at a time how could I do this with jQuery.

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable();
} );
```

```css
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
  #sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; background: #ddd }
  #sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="checkbox" name="item_select"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="checkbox" name="item_select"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="checkbox" name="item_select"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="checkbox" name="item_select"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="checkbox" name="item_select"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="checkbox" name="item_select"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><input type="checkbox" name="item_select"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```